# Break out of multiple for loops in Ceylon

Tags: ceylon

Let's say I have I several nested `for` loops in Ceylon. How do I break out of all the loops:

```
variable Integer? something = null;
for (i in 0:3) {
  for (j in 0:3) {
    for (k in 0:3) {
      something = someFunction(i,j,k);
      if (something exists) {
        // break out of everything, we found it
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to wrap the whole thing in a closure and then call it using return when you want to break out of everything:

```
Integer? doLoops() {
  for (i in 0:3) {
    for (j in 0:3) {
      for (k in 0:3) {
        Integer? something = someFunction(i,j,k);
        if (something exists) {
          return something;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
Integer? something = doLoops();
```

Because Ceylon supports closures, you can also read and write other values outside the function in the scope where `doLoops` is defined.

Answer (score 5):

You can use comprehension and stream processing syntax instead:

```
Iterable<Integer?> stream = {
    for (i in 0:3) for (j in 0:3) for (k in 0:3) someFunction(i,j,k)
};

Integer? = stream.coalesced.first;
```

This will work as expected because `{ for ... }` comprehension creates an `Iterable` that is lazily evaluated.

The `coalesced` attribute of the iterable return another lazy iterable that skips all `null` values in the original.

Then just ask for the first value of the remaining iterable and there's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to use `else` blocks on the `for` loops:

```
shared void run() {
    variable Integer? x = null;
    for (i in 0:3) {
        for (j in 0:3) {
            for (k in 0:3) {
                value n = i*j*k;
                if (n > 18) {
                    x = n;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    } else {
        x = null;
    }
    print(x);
}
```

In general, place

```
else {
    continue;
}
break;
```

after every `for`’s closing brace.

(Note: Ideally, the variable being assigned – `x` in my example, `something` in yours – wouldn’t need to be `variable`, since it’s assigned exactly once. However, the typechecker currently [can’t prove that](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/issues/5948).)

How does it work? The `else` after a `for` loop is executed iff that loop ran to completion without any `break`. In that case, we want to `continue` the outer loop as well; otherwise – that is, if we broke from the inner loop – we want to `break` from the outer one as well.

This could be written more succinctly with the following syntax proposed in [ceylon/ceylon#3223](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/issues/3223):

```
for (a in b) {
    for (x in y) {
        if (something) {
            break;
        }
    } then { // opposite of else: runs iff there was a break in the inner loop
        break;
    }
}
```

---

I wouldn’t recommend this solution, for three reasons:

- It’s even less readable than your closure solution. The `for {} else {}` feature is fairly obscure, and the meaning isn’t obvious at all if you’re not familiar with it, making the code incomprehensible to the casual reader.
- It bloats the code a lot in every surrounding loop (not just once), also making it unreadable.
- If you want to have code in the outer loops after the inner loops, you’ll have to duplicate it: the `else` block and the code after it both need a copy.